# Apache camel - Error mail handling for invalid data formats

Tags: java, email, csv, apache-camel

Can someone guide me through error email configuration for invalid data format in csv files

Answer (score 3):

You can add an exception block in your route where you can send an email.
Example pseudo code:

```
        onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(true)
        .beanRef(CreateErrorMailBean...)
        .to("smtp://...")
        end();
```

You can also have more than 1 of this exception blocks, if you want to differ between different types of exceptions(in your case maybe DataFormatException?)